# Equation of tangent to the curve

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The equation of the curve is:

$$x=\frac{\left(y-2\right)^{2}}{y}$$

The tangent to the curve is passing through the origin. Find the equation of the tangent.

My solution:

$xy=(y-2)^2$

⇒ $x=\frac{(y-2)^2}{y}$

Now, differentiating both sides with respect to y, we get,

$\frac{dx}{dy}= \frac{(y-2)(y+2)}{y^2}$

Therefore, $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y^2}{(y-2)(y+2)}$

The equation of tangent is given by, $y-y_1$= $\frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$.

Since, tangent passes through origin, so at $(0,0)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Thus, the equation of tangent is: $y-0= 0(x-0)$

⇒ $y$=$0$  (i.e X-axis)

My confusion: Tangent exists at a point on the curve, but looking at the graph of $xy=(y-2)^{2}$, we can see that X-axis is the asymptote, so how can the tangent be $y=0$ i.e. X-axis when curve doesn't even touch it?

Following is the graph of $x=\frac{\left(y-2\right)^{2}}{y}$

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I have tried the solution for it. I have a slight confusion. Please look at the last part and help me understand how the tangent  $y=0$  will be the answer. If my solution is incorrect, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Looking at your plot, the line tangent to the point $(x,y)=(0,2)$  (i.e. the line $x=0$, the $y$-axis) is tangent to the curve and goes through the origin. The equation $xy=(y-2)^2$ does not implicitly define $y$ as  function of $x$ around the point $(0,2)$, so you cannot calculate $dy/dx$ there (the curve has an infinite slope).

Comment: But shouldn't a tangent touch the curve at a point? If the line acting as the tangent doesn't touch the curve at some point, then can that line be called the tangent to that curve?

Comment: What are you responding to? Who has said that the tangent line doesn't touch the curve?

Comment: @smcc I was responding to you. My confusion is:   can $y=0$ i.e. X-axis be called a tangent to the curve despite it doesn't touch the curve at all? Shouldn't a line just touch the curve at a point to be called a tangent to the curve?
A vertical tangent( Y-axis or $x=0$ at $(0,2)$ )does exist and it can be called the tangent since it touches the curve at $(0,2)$ and also passes through $(0,0)$. However, the equation of this tangent can't be determined as the slope is infinite. How do I obtain the eqn of the tangent to the curve then?

Answer (score 1):

> The equation of tangent is given by, $y-y_1$= $\frac{dy}{dx}(x-x_1)$.
>
> Since, tangent passes through origin, so at $(0,0)$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

I think your mistake is here. Since the tangent line to the curve at $(x_1,y_1)$ passes through the origin, we know $y-y_1 = \frac{dy}{dx}(x_1,y_1)(x-x_1)$ is satisfied by $x=0$ and $y=0$. That tells you something about $(x_1,y_1)$: namely, that $\frac{dy}{dx}(x_1,y_1) = \frac{y_1}{x_1}$. So you want to find solutions to $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x}$.

Another possibility is a vertical tangent line. If this vertical tangent line passes through the origin, it must be the $y$-axis. So look for points $(0,y_1)$ on the curve with $\frac{dx}{dy}(0,y_1) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, I agree that there should be another vertical tangent line i.e. Y-axis ($x=0$)since the question states that the tangent passes through the origin. The point besides the origin that the vertical tangent line passes through is $(0,2)$. If the tangent is Y-axis, the slope of the tangent would be infinity, and thus the equation of the tangent can't be obtained through slope point form. How would you obtain the equation of the tangent to the curve in this case?

Comment: Additionally,  can $y=0$ i.e. X-axis be called a tangent to the curve despite it doesn't touch the curve at all? Shouldn't a line just touch the curve at a point to be called a tangent to the curve?

Comment: @Pythagoras. The vertical line through $(x_1,y_1)$ has equation $x=x_1$. If that line is tangent to the curve at $(x_1,y_1)$, then $\frac{dx}{dy} = 0$ at $(x_1,y_1)$. To find $\frac{dx}{dy}$, you can differentiate the equation for the curve, keeping $x$ implicitly a function of $y$.

Comment: Since the line $y=0$ doesn't intersect the curve at all, it can't be a tangent line to the curve.